# Joint definition leads to No transform from [] to [base_link] on an arm robot

Tags: gazebo, rviz, robotic-arm, urdf

As stated, I am encountering this error when launching a ROS 2 simulation. I am currently using ROS 2 Iron and Gazebo Classic.

I am spawning the robot system from a pythonlaunch file as it follows:

```
spawn_robot = Node(
       package='gazebo_ros', 
       executable='spawn_entity.py',
       arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                   '-entity', 'arm', '-x' , '0', '-y', '0', '-z', '0.1'],
       remappings=[
           ('/camera_R/image_raw', 'image_R'),
           ('/camera_L/image_raw', 'image_L'),
           ('/laser_controller/out', 'laser_scan')],
       output='screen')
```

The robot description is parsed as it follows:

```
xacro_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(pkg_name), 'models', 'arm', 'model.xacro')
    robot_description_raw = xacro.process_file(xacro_file).toxml()

    params = {'robot_description': robot_description_raw, 'verbose': True, 'use_sim_time': True}
    rsp = Node(package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[params])
```

When I try to visualize it in Rviz I encounter the error No transform from [shoulder] to [base_link] and the following picture:

[image: Rviz visualization]

The xacro file that contains the model has the following definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from robot_models/models/simple_DDR/model.xacro | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <xacro:include filename="$(find robot_models)/models/arm/variables.xacro"/>
    
    <link name="base_link"></link>
    
    <link name="base">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="${xmass_base} ${ymass_base} ${zmass_base}" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <mass value="${mass_base}"/>
            <inertia ixx="${ixx_base}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${iyy_base}" iyz="0.0" izz="${izz_base}"/>
    </inertial>
    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_models)/models/arm/meshes/collision/base.stl" scale="1 1 1"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <virtual>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_models)/models/arm/meshes/visual/base.dae" scale="1 1 1"/>
            </geometry>
        </virtual>
    </link>
    <joint name="joint_base" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="base"/>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="shoulder">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <mass value="${mass_shoulder}"/>
        <inertia ixx="${ixx_shoulder}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${iyy_shoulder}" iyz="0.0" izz="${izz_shoulder}"/>
        </inertial>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_models)/models/arm/meshes/collision/shoulder.stl" scale="1 1 1"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>

    <joint name="joint_shoulder" type="revolute">
        <parent link="base"/>
        <child link="shoulder"/>
        <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.163"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <limit effort="150.0" lower="-6.28318530718" upper="6.28318530718" velocity="3.14"/>
        <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
    </joint>
</robot>
```

Answer (score 0):

The robot state publisher used to get the visualization in rviz requires the joint states to be published, see [here (first paragraph)](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher).

Because the `joint_base` joint is fixed, the transformation is already available. The `joint_shoulder` transformation is unknown (without the gazebo plugin) because this joint can move.

You can get the joint states by using following plugin in your gazebo robot model:

### Gazebo Classic

Install the required package (the metapackage with the plugin)

```
sudo apt install ros-iron-gazebo-ros-pkgs
```

Add this to your model

```
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher"
        filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher.so">
    <joint_name>joint_shoulder</joint_name>
</plugin>
```

### Gazebo Sim

Install the required package (the metapackage with the plugin)

```
sudo apt install ros-iron-ros-gz
```

Add this to your model

```
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gz::sim::systems::JointStatePublisher"
            filename="gz-sim-joint-state-publisher-system">
        <topic>/joint_states</topic>
        <joint_name>joint_shoulder</joint_name>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Comment: Is this also valid for classic?

Comment: I missed the "Classic" part of your question. Updated the answer to include the Gazebo Classic approach.